# Stop Jquery animation on mouse over or hover

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseover

I want to stop or clear the animation of an element while it is being hovered and return when the its not. Here's my code:

```
function blink(){
        $('#unitedkingdom, #germany, #korea, #philippines,
        #indonesia').delay(400).fadeTo(800,0.7).delay(800).fadeTo(800,1, blink);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

            blink();

        $('#unitedkingdom').hover(function(){
            $(this).stop(blink); //I'm trying to STOP the function i declared from above
            $('#uk').animate({opacity:1},300);
        });
        $('#germany').hover(function(){
            $('#ger').animate({opacity:1},300);
        });
        $('#korea').hover(function(){
            $('#kor').animate({opacity:1},300);
        });
        $('#philippines').hover(function(){
            $('#phil').animate({opacity:1},300);
        });
        $('#indonesia').hover(function(){
            $('#ind').animate({opacity:1},300);
        });
    });
```

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Have you tried calling stop with no parameters? It does not take a function as a parameter like you are doing.

Comment: yes, I already tried that one out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
$(this).stop(true);
```

jQuery `.stop()` docs - http://api.jquery.com/stop/